# option select with razor bootstrap from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, razor, html-select

I want to combine with those two sheets of code :

```
<select class="selectpicker" >
    <option>ouvert</option>
    <option>ferme</option>
    <option>reçu</option>
</select>
```

And this :

```
 <div class="editor-label">

     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.etattik)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.etattik)
 </div>
```

the select field should display data from the database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you are populating YourViewModel.etattik to the value from the database in your controller action. Once done, use `@Html.DropDownListFor` for a `select` list like below:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => m.etattik, 
    new SelectList(
              new List<Object>{ 
                   new { value = 0 , text = "text1"  },
                   new { value = 1 , text = "text2" },
                   new { value = 2 , text = "text3"}
                },
              "value",
              "text",
               2
    )
)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.etattik)
```

Put your desired values in the `value` and `text` of the listitems created above.

You can even create this list collection in your controller. In that case your code will look like below:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => m.etattik, 
    new SelectList(
        Model.ListItems,
        "id",
        "name",
        Model.etattik
    )
)
```

The strings `"id"` and `"name"` are the attributes of the listitems.

Comment: it doesn't work with me ..I got this in the field : { value =0, text =text1 }

Comment: @biba I have edited my answer. Please and check let me know if it helps.